# How to quantitatively analyse a semi-structured interview?

Tags: survey, psychology

I am looking to design a study that involves interviewing children by asking them questions that relate to their values, practices, and identities. Children will be migrants who could identify to varying extents with both their heritage culture and adopted (receiving) culture values, practices, and identities.

I'm a bit stuck on thinking of a good way to organize and analyze the data quantitatively.

Variables:

- Values (influenced by heritage and receiving culture, + interaction)
- Practices (influenced by heritage and receiving culture, + interaction)
- Identifications (aligned with heritage or receiving culture, or both).

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Where are you stuck? I can think of two big places where you could get stuck in this sort of analysis: 1) Getting the data from the interview into a form that be analyzed statistically or 2) Doing the analysis.

Comment: Have you searched the literature thoroughly to see whether any psychometrically sound (valid and reliable) quantitative scales already exist that assess your constructs?  If so, it would save you a lot of work on validation, plus saving you from taking on the risk that your method starting from scratch might not end up as valid/reliable as you would like.

Answer (score 1):

First off, quantitative analyses are - in my opinion - rarely the best way to approach qualitative data such as interviews. That being said, I think that there are some good ways to model the interconnectedness of topics using Markov chain models. There was a paper by Laurie R. Weingart et al. in the Journal of Experimental Social Psychology, which might be useful as inspiration. Link [here](http://www.bus.emory.edu/prietula/weingart-prietula-seq.pdf).